# CTreeCtrl: checkboxes and spacebar?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I use a tree control with TVS_CHECKBOXES style set. I do not need
checkboxes near some root items. To remove a checkbox near particular
item I use something like:

m_ctrlTree.SetItemState( hItem, 0, TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK );

This works like a charm until I select such an item and press spacebar.
The checkbox appears again magically. What do I do wrong?

Comment: try to catch the spacebar event (NM_KEYDOWN)

Comment: what should I need to do after catching this event.Moreover after catching the event how should we check whether the item got checkbox if it got checkbox how should we remove it.Can you please help me out to get this done.